# How to stop stageros from publishing its transforms?

Tags: ros, stageros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I stop stageros from publishing its transforms and all of its published topics? Is there a simple remapping possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11189/how-to-stop-stageros-from-publishing-its-transforms?/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

stage's published topics (including `tf`) aren't in a namespace, so you can't remap them in them one go.  But you can remap them individually using the [usual remapping arguments](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments).

E.g., at the command-line (assuming one robot):

```
roscd stage     
./bin/stageros odom:=stage/odom base_scan:=stage/base_scan tf:=stage/tf world/willow-erratic.world
```

Out of curiosity, why do you want to remap stage's outputs?

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-09-14**:
I tried that, and found that `/tf` was still published in the global namespace.  That probably ought to be ticketed.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-13**:
For a launchfile you can just set the namespace to stage once using the ns attribute.

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-09-12**:
Do I need to do something like :  and set tf_prefix ="old_transform" within the launch file? There's only 1 robot running.

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-09-12**:
My config files are meant to run on a physical robot and they publish all needed topics and transforms. To debug certain issues, I thought it a good idea to see how the same thing runs in simulation on stage. Hence I  need to quench out all topics published by stageros.